# Disable a button when certain condition is matched

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two items P1_ENDTIME,P1_CURRENTDATE. The first item(P1_ENDTIME)has value which i am getting from interactive grid column. And in second item(P1_CURRENTDATE) is having current date.

I want to disable the button when current date(P1_CURRENTDATE) value is higher than end time (P1_ENDTIME).

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new page item P1_ISFUTURE
- Create a dynamic action on change of P1_CURRENTDATE
- Add a true action of type "Execute Server-side Code"

  - PL/Sql Code:

```
IF TO_DATE(:P1_ENDTIME,'DD-MON-YY') > TO_DATE(:P1_CURRENTDATE,'DD-MON-YY') THEN
  :P1_ISFUTURE := 'Y';
END IF;
```

- Items to submit: P1_ENDTIME, P1_CURRENTDATE
- Items to return: P1_ISFUTURE
- Add a true action of type "Disable" for the button with client-side condition of type "Item = Value" and values P1_ISFUTURE, Y
- Add a true action of type "Enable" for the button with client-side condition of type "Item != Value" and values P1_ISFUTURE, Y

Side Note: You don't need to store the current date in P1_CURRENTDATE. Instead you could just use

```
IF TO_DATE(:P1_ENDTIME,'DD-MON-YY') > SYSDATE THEN
  :P1_ISFUTURE := 'Y';
END IF;
```